# Взаимодействие WinApi Python

Tags: python, winapi, print, hook

Друзья! У меня возник некоторый вопрос о перехвате сочетаний клавиш в питоне. А конкретнее мне нужно написать программу которая отправляла бы файл сокетом на принт-сервер и печатала его. Однако у меня случился затык на перехвате Ctrl+P а конкретнее подмена стандартной распечатки на мою, кастомную, так как стандартный smb протокол в разных версиях винды жутко кривой и мне необходимо разработать универсальный способ для печати. Буду благодарен. В данный момент курю библиотеки pywin32, keyboard, pyhook, но что то не выходит. Все спасибо!

Comment: и про сокеты, и про сетевой файловый доступ, и про подмену распечатки, и про перехват нажатий клавиш. начните с чего-то одного. вам же проще будет.

Comment: ну вот я начал с перехвата, все остальное почти готовое

Comment: Ну хоть код какой-то добавьте. А то непонятно, с чем именно затык.

Comment: у меня затык с самим пониманием как перехватить ctrl+p (так что бы попутно закрыть стандартное окно распечатки) кода нету, сижу курю мануалы и ничего понять не могу